# Using Pyspark, the regex between two characters gets text and numbers, but not date

Tags: regex, pyspark

Using Pyspark regex_extract() I can substring between two characters in the string.  It is grabbing the text and numbers, but is not grabbing the dates.

```
data = [('2345', '<Date>1999/12/12 10:00:05</Date>'),
('2398', '<Crew>crewIdXYZ</Crew>'),
('2328', '<Latitude>0.8252644369443788</Latitude>'),        
('3983', '<Longitude>-2.1915840465066916<Longitude>')]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID', 'values'])

df.show(truncate=False)

+----+-----------------------------------------+
|ID  |values                                   |
+----+-----------------------------------------+
|2345|<Date>1999/12/12 10:00:05</Date>         |
|2398|<Crew>crewIdXYZ</Crew>                   |
|2328|<Latitude>0.8252644369443788</Latitude>  |
|3983|<Longitude>-2.1915840465066916<Longitude>|
+----+-----------------------------------------+
df_2 = df.withColumn('vals', regexp_extract(col('values'), '(.)((?<=>)[^<:]+(?=:?<))', 2)) 
df_2.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|ID  |values                                   |vals               |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|2345|<Date>1999/12/12 10:00:05</Date>         |                   |
|2398|<Crew>crewIdXYZ</Crew>                   |crewIdXYZ          |
|2328|<Latitude>0.8252644369443788</Latitude>  |0.8252644369443788 |
|3983|<Longitude>-2.1915840465066916<Longitude>|-2.1915840465066916|
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

What can I add to the regex statement to get the date as well?

Comment: just remove the tags: `df.withColumn('vals', regexp_replace('values', '<[^>]*>', ''))`

Answer (score 0):

@jxc Thanks.  Here is what made it work:

```
df_2 = df.withColumn('vals', regexp_extract(col('values'), '(.)((?<=>)[^>]+(?=:?<))', 2))
df_2.show(truncate=False)
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|ID  |values                                   |vals               |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|2345|<Date>1999/12/12 10:00:05</Date>         |1999/12/12 10:00:05|
|2398|<Crew>crewIdXYZ</Crew>                   |crewIdXYZ          |
|2328|<Latitude>0.8252644369443788</Latitude>  |0.8252644369443788 |
|3983|<Longitude>-2.1915840465066916<Longitude>|-2.1915840465066916|
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You obfuscated the pattern quite a lot: `.(?<=>)` is equal to `>`. `[^>]+`  is greedy and matches up to the `>` or end of string and backtracks to `<`, as `:` is optional, so `:?` is redundant. By adding `<` to the negated character class you could reduce redundant backtracking. See [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59641653/3832970).

Comment: Justin ideally it shouldn't be a answer it should be a comment on @Wiktor answer or reply on comment of question

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
>([^<>]+)<
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fArcss/1). The regex matches a `>`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `<` and `>`, and then just matches `>`. The *ncol* argument should be set to `1` since the value you need is in Group 1:

```
df_2 = df.withColumn('vals', regexp_extract(col('values'), '>([^<>]+)<', 1))
df_2.show(truncate=False)

+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|ID  |values                                   |vals               |
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
|2345|<Date>1999/12/12 10:00:05</Date>         |1999/12/12 10:00:05|
|2398|<Crew>crewIdXYZ</Crew>                   |crewIdXYZ          |
|2328|<Latitude>0.8252644369443788</Latitude>  |0.8252644369443788 |
|3983|<Longitude>-2.1915840465066916<Longitude>|-2.1915840465066916|
+----+-----------------------------------------+-------------------+
```